# Copy app settings from external file into app.config

Tags: c#, .net, installation, app-config

I'm trying to figure out what the best practice is for updating an app.config file of an existing application to include new app settings, without overwriting pre-existing settings values.

So, to start from the beginning, I have a project that gets built into an MSI by a Visual Studio setup project, and that MSI is used to install the application.  This application is already installed at probably 1000+ locations.  Now, in a new version of the application, we have a new app setting to define a webservice endpoint.  The setup project, however, will not deploy the new app.config with the new setting, because setup projects are dumb like that and they will only install an app.config if either it doesn't already exist, or if the existing one has matching created and modified dates, to avoid overwriting user defined configuration.

Now, since I can't overwrite the app.config, I figured that maybe I will deploy the app.config changes as a separate XML file, and at application startup, I will load this separate XML file, copy all the settings out of it, compare to what's in the actual app.config file, and anything that's missing I will save into the app.config file.

But I'm having problems loading config from an external XML file and copying it over to the app.config.  How would I go about doing this?  Is there any other better way to manage updating an app.config file?  What is best practice?

I'm more familiar with Java, and this would be a very simple thing to do with Properties files, but doesn't seem so simple with .NET config files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no out-of-the-box method as far as I know.

I'd do it by parsing the file into an XDocument, then checking whether doc.Element("settingName") is null. If it is, then that setting doesn't exist and you can add a default value. If the node does exist, the the user has defined a custom setting.

Comment: I had the same thought, but it seems stupid that you have to parse this as XML instead of being able to just straight up load both files as Configuration objects and compare the two, so as to move new settings from the new file to the pre-existing file.  I mean, .NET knows how to load a .config file - why doesn't it let us just load as many as we want from wherever we want, and manipulate them any way we want, like you can with a Java Properties file?

Comment: I did implement it this way and it works fine, but it's kind of a pain in the ass.  Seriously, it's so easy in Java to just open Properties files from anywhere you want and load everything into a Properties object, so you could compare, and copy from one to the other to your heart's extent.  It should be just as easy in .NET to load multiple config files without having to parse the XML.

Comment: It sounds like a good excuse to start an open source wrapper library to me. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a link to an external app.config. 
http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2008/06/Keep-your-config-clean-with-external-config-files.aspx

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article969-external-appsetting-file-for-your-appsettings-in-config-file.aspx

Comment: This isn't what I asked for.  I don't need to link two config files together.  I need to load two separate versions of the same config file, compare the settings in them, and copy from old one to the new one.

Comment: First link broken